# Can typescript's Int8ArrayConstructor type definition be simplified

Tags: typescript

I'm checking the following type definition in typescript core https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v4.0.5/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1966-L1970

Can this be simplified to:

```
interface Int8ArrayConstructor {
    readonly prototype: Int8Array;
    new(length: number): Int8Array;
    new(array: ArrayLike<number> /*| ArrayBufferLike */): Int8Array;
    new(buffer: ArrayBufferLike, byteOffset?: number, length?: number): Int8Array;
```

that is, from the second `new` line the `ArrayBufferLike` type can be deleted, right?

Moreover, if `new Int8Array(xyz)` is called with an `ArrayBufferLike` as an argument, into which of the above declaration lines will that be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost, the difference is when you have a variable of type `ArrayLike<number> | ArrayBufferLike`  ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcMGcIAmAkuABwCCUUcAngMIYi5hQCuCYGUyA3gFDJByKBDgFGAGxrIsmTmBpYIALmQkwFKrQDcAoSAgB3ABQSIIAOZgAFqpCsAtgCNoASlXrN1GrqHIDJnBaNKqU3gAywADWEAA89s7QAHzIAPQAVAA+yGG0AEKsMDDQkTHI6anuamS5PnqCAcZOhcVQocEFRSXREAA0yE40kADyRfhgAPx2ji5Q-WaWNlP+M24eNcG6AL58fAQQCBJBKAiMzGiYOPgEDEws7JxtF9h4hJ61t8xsHFy7+4fHZCnO7IfYwAD6zS6T1qnVapQguj2ByOIiBZzAyActEhEHBEGANmg7W8cO6ZWytQR8VWUCSSIC1Q0tWMYMhLTcukZ72CxmxNFx+MJ1jcu0Z6Be10+9x+UFZEAhUNarj44surxuGO+jz5OJcQqJUFcaVSyGgmG4IpEQA))

```
interface ProposedInt8ArrayConstructor {
    readonly prototype: Int8Array;
    new(length: number): Int8Array;
    new(array: ArrayLike<number> /*| ArrayBufferLike */): Int8Array;
    new(buffer: ArrayBufferLike, byteOffset?: number, length?: number): Int8Array;
}

declare const ProposedConstructor: ProposedInt8ArrayConstructor

declare const def_buffer: ArrayBufferLike;

declare const may_be_either: ArrayBufferLike | ArrayLike<number>;

new Int8Array(def_buffer); // resolves to the second overload but 3rd would be valid
new Int8Array(may_be_either) // valid

new ProposedConstructor(def_buffer) // resolves to 3rd overload
new ProposedConstructor(may_be_either) // ERROR HERE!
```

as for which overload they resolve to you can read the comments next to the lines in the above code block or in general hover over the call signature in the playground or other intellisense enabled environment:

[image]
so it resolves to the second overload because there are no extra optional arguments where as with your proposal:
[image]

it resolves to the third.

Comment: Hmm. This is such a strong insight. Good job. And for the second part of the question, into which branch will "new Int8Array(ArrayBufferLike)" resolve? I mean, because the return type for both of the last branches is the same it doesn't matter in this specific case, but in general...

Comment: `// resolves to the second overload but 3rd would be valid` and `// resolves to 3rd overload` are in the code block :) added a little more info now though.

Comment: Thanks. It is just crazy that TS accepts something like this. For example https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcMGcIAmAkuABwCCUUcAngMIYi5hQCuCYGUyA3gFDJByEBADuACjhVaALmSVqNAEKsYMaABlgAawgBKOSFYBbAEbQA3AKEiJp1eqhyFtFWs079c5lFABzKwBfPj4CCAQAGykUBEZmNEwcfAIGJhZ2TicE7DxCEjAKaXo49I4uELDI6ORYtOQwmAB9e3csl2UHD10rPlr402QAXmExbKTCVJ8MrnEG5s6oPRCBgGpkAGYrIA and infers b as a number.

Comment: are you running into a case where the return type is different? usually the "resolve to first viable overload" works pretty well but if you have a reasonable use case that is being blocked by this I'd love to see it since I'm trying to compile evidence to get it changed.

Comment: I don't have. Only made up example on top of the above. But I see two holes in the above logic. One is that calling my proposed constructor is not allowed with ArrayLike<number> | ArrayBufferLike and the second is the resolution into first satisfying branch.

Comment: I'm not totally sure which logic you are referring to to have holes, but one thing is that technically the type `number | ArrayBufferLike` would be a viable input to the constructor but because there is no single overload that supports that type it gets rejected in the same way `ArrayLike<number> | ArrayBufferLike` gets rejected from your proposed version. I've been vaguely been trying to find some logic to reduce overloads in a way that would allow these cases without removing any capabilities from overloading but am yet to figure out a way. (if someone did we'd have a better system :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224304/discussion-between-croraf-and-tadhg-mcdonald-jensen).